# JS var with multiple values

Tags: javascript, var

Something I can't understand :

I got a function opening the same page `<div id="page">` but with different contents depending the clicked button in menu:

```
<nav>
    <button onclick="openPage(1)">PAGE 1</button> 
    <button onclick="openPage(2)">PAGE 2</button>
    <button onclick="openPage(3)">PAGE 3</button>
</nav>
```

Then the function:

```
function openPage(p){

    var move=0;  // define a var for USER action

    if(p==1){
         document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = text_1;  // content preloaded
    }
    else if(p==2){
         document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = text_2;
    }
    else if(p==3){
         document.getElementById('page').innerHTML = text_3;
    }

    // then on the top of the page (absolute + z-index) I add a HTML object:

    document.getElementById('page').innerHTML += '<aside id="pictures">content</aside>';

    // what I'm now trying to do is to remove this object once USER move its mouse on it 

    document.getElementById('pictures').addEventListener("mousemove",function(event) {
       setTimeout(function(){
          move+=1;  // increase the val each second
       },1e3)
       console.log('move'+p+' = '+move)  // control value
       if(move>100){
          document.getElementById('pictures').style.display = "none";  // OK, it works
          move=0;  // reinit the var
       }
   });  
}
```

Now the surprise:

console on page 1

```
   move1 = 0
   move1 = 1
   ...
   move1 = 99
   move1 = 100    //  'pictures' disappears
```

console on page 2

```
   move1 = 41
   move2 = 0
   ...
   move1 = 58
   move1 = 17
   ...
   move1 = 100    //  'pictures' disappears
   move2 = 59
```

console on page 3

```
   move1 = 15
   move2 = 88
   move3 = 0
   ...
   move1 = 37
   move2 = 100    //  'pictures' disappears
   move3 = 12
   ...
```

My var 'move' got 3 simultaneous values... how is it possible?

Comment: You will need to remove the existing event listener before adding a new one

Comment: OK, thanks. You mean each event listener got its own value of the same var?

Comment: you bind a new event listener each time you do a button click so by the third click you fire three events everytime you do mousemove

Comment: consider cache of `document.getElementById('page')` so you hit the DOM less.

Comment: Look into a delegated event and put it on the container element re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation  OR move the variable and the listener outside of the function...

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your issue is that you're adding an event listener every time you call the `openPage` function. This means that if you click on multiple buttons, each one will have its own event listener attached to the `#pictures` element. Now, when the `mousemove` event is triggered, all these listeners will execute simultaneously, causing the `move` variable to increment multiple times per second.

The fix for this would be to *[remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)* the existing event listener before adding a new one.

```js
let handler; // to hold the event listener function
const pictureEl = document.getElementById('pictures');
let move = 0;

function openPage(p){

   // Remove existing event listener
   if (handler) { // <-- Check here
       pictureEl.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler);
   }
   
   handler = function(event) {
       // ...Rest
       }
   };
   // Add new event listener
   pictureEl.addEventListener("mousemove", handler);
// ...rest
```

Comment: Why not just create a variable and pass it to the listener you only have to put in one time? OR better yet a delegated event listener re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation

Comment: See my example where I added a delegated event for the button clicks IF you want to do that with the picture part.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss. If you click on the edited link on my answer, I added an alternative approach which you've mentioned but then I saw your answer(upvoted it) and removed it. I got what you're referring and yes I agree with it since it avoids the need to manage multiple event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different take on this where I leverage the dataset and put values on the buttons and pass them around.
I also used a class on the element to hide and to illustrate use when you click the button I remove it to show again.  I had no idea on layout so I just put the picture in the "page" and added a span - NOTE: this avoids hitting the DOM to add/remove the element and the mousemove event listener.

```js
var move = 0;
var textOptions = ["I am text one", "I am text two", "I am text three"];

document.getElementById('my-page')
  .addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      move += 1;
    }, 1000);
    console.log('move' + event.currentTarget.dataset.targ + ' = ' + move);
    if (move > 100) {
      event.currentTarget.classList.add("hide-me");
      move = 0;
    }
  });
document.querySelector('.my-nav')
  .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('my-page').classList.remove("hide-me");
    const buttonTarget = event.target.dataset.target;
    event.currentTarget.dataset.targ = buttonTarget;
    console.log(buttonTarget);
    openPage(buttonTarget);
  });

function openPage(p) {
  const myPage = document.getElementById('my-page');
  myPage.querySelector('.first-part').textConent = textOptions[p];
  const myPic = myPage.querySelector('.my-pictures');
  myPic.textContent = `content Page: ${p}`;
  myPage.dataset.targ = p;
}
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<nav class="my-nav">
  <button data-target="1">PAGE 1</button>
  <button data-target="2">PAGE 2</button>
  <button data-target="3">PAGE 3</button>
</nav>

<div id="my-page" data-targ="x"><span class="first-part">Hi! Click buttons!</span>
  <div class="my-pictures" id="pictures">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another (simpliest ?) way:

```
 var move=0;  // placed out of functions

 function openPage(p){
     getElementById('pictures').removeEventListener("mousemove",outPicts);
     move=0;  // reinit the var

     .... (same as previous)

     getElementById('pictures').addEventListener("mousemove",outPicts);
 }

 // put mousemove event in another function:

 function outPicts(p){
    setTimeout(function(){
        move+=1;
    },1e3)
    console.log('move = '+move)
    if(move>100){
        document.getElementById('pictures').style.display = "none";        
     }
  }
```

works as expected